# pip list doesn't show location correctly when installing with poetry

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

Earlier when I poetry installed my local package its correct path used to be shown when I pip list

Old versions
poetry: 1.0.2

pip list

```sh
package                          version                        location
----------                       ---------                      ------------
local_pacage                      1.0.0                         /Users/username/project
```

Updated version
poetry: 1.1.6
pip version was also updated don't remember the old version

pip list

```sh
package                              version                      
----------                          ---------                   
local_pacage                       1.0.0
```

pip list -v shows the location as site packages always even when installed from other path using poetry.
Earlier it used to show correctly.
Note: Installer column shows installer as poetry, it's just the location

```sh
package                              version              location                                                          Installer
----------                          ---------             ----------                                                     ------------
local_pacage                       1.0.0                   /Users/username/site-packges                    poetry
```

Any idea what could be the reason. Could it be a change in poetry or pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of how poetry installs the package in editable mode has changed between 1.0 and 1.1.

Prior 1.1 an egg-link file was create. Since 1.1 a `.pth` file is used as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html). This change leads to the behavior you see.

Also see abn's answers in the issue tracker:

- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2725#issuecomment-663851601
- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2725#issuecomment-663911016